# How can I make a CMFCRibbonEdit automatically convert contents to uppercase?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack, cmfcribbonpanel

I am using the MFC Feature pack in Visual Studio 2008. I have an edit box (CMFCRibbonEdit) in a ribbon that I would like only to contain uppercase letters. I know that I can pass ES_UPPERCASE to the "Create" method, however "Create" is called from the Ribbon itself, and not explicitly by my code.

To add the edit box to my ribbon, I call this:

```
CMFCRibbonPanel* pPanel = pCategoryViewer->AddPanel("Panel Title");
CMFCRibbonEdit *cEdit = new CMFCRibbonPanel( ID_MYEDITBOX, 60, "Edit Title" );
pPanel->Add( cEdit );
```

Based on what I read on MSDN I saw I could overload the "CreateEdit" function of CMFCRibbonEdit. I tried that, but it didn't work.

```
class UpperCaseRibbonEdit : public CMFCRibbonEdit
{
public:
  UpperCaseRibbonEdit( UINT nID, int nWidth, LPCTSTR lpszLabel )
    :CMFCRibbonEdit( nID, nWidth, lpszLabel )
  {}

  CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl* CreateEdit( CWnd* pWndParent, DWORD dwEditStyle )
  {
    return CMFCRibbonEdit::CreateEdit( pWndParent, dwEditStyle | ES_UPPERCASE );
  }
};
```

I also tried making this call after initializing my ribbon and its controls. This didn't work either.

```
HWND editHwnd = GetDlgItem( ID_MYEDITBOX )->GetSafeHwnd();
SetWindowLong(editHwnd, GWL_STYLE, (LONG)GetWindowLong(editHwnd, GWL_STYLE) | ES_UPPERCASE);
```

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: The reason your solution doesn't work is because the control is actually a rich edit, which doesn't support `ES_UPPERCASE` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774367.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As I think you already know, CMFCRibbonEdit has inside a member variable `CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl* m_pWndEdit;` which type that is descendant of CRichEditCtrl. So, as the page @Stanich's comment states ES_UPPERCASE is not supported for it.

I guess your best option is: in your derived class you do not forget to put `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(EN_CHANGE, OnChange)` in the message map; and looking for the base class original code:

```
void CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl::OnChange()
{
    CString strText;
    GetWindowText(strText);

    m_edit.m_strEdit = strText;
    m_edit.SetEditText(strText);
}
```

change strText in yours to be all caps letters after the GetWindowText line.